# C++: Backspace characters not showing in stdout?

Tags: c++, std

I am implementing a shell that has command history. When the user presses the up or down arrow, the text in the current line is replaced with the previous or next command.

The algorithm I'm planning on implementing is fairly simple. If the current command has k characters, I output k '\b' characters to delete the k characters int he current line and then output the selected command to the line.

However, I'm trying to start out with something basic, such as seeing if outputting '\b' characters even works in deleting characters from the current `stdout` line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout << "asdf";
    cout << "\b\b" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above piece of code is:

```
asdf
```

When I expect:

```
as
```

*Important*: I want to delete characters **after** they are outputted to `stdout`.

Comment: On most terminals backspace does not erase characters, it just moves the cursor back one space. You may want to output some spaces after `\b`.

Comment: Like `"\b\b \b"` (for each character you want to erase) Other option is to use ANSI escapes and back the cursor up and clear to end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ANSI escape codes. Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout << "asdf";
    cout<<"\b\b\b\b\033[J";
    return 0;
}
```

`\033` stands for `ESC` and `[J` is a parameter to the code. `ESC[J` clears the screen from the cursor to the end of the screen. For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fe_Escape_sequences

As @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. mentioned, `\b` simply moves the cursor back one space, and does not rewrite anything, for most implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use ncurses and readline libraries.

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline-dev
git clone https://github.com/ulfalizer/readline-and-ncurses
cd readline-and-ncurses 
make
rlncurses
```

My environment:

```
lsb_release -d ; uname -r ; g++ --version | head -1
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```